# How to get the original file name of a module in PyKD?

Tags: python, windbg, pykd

I have a module in [PyKD](https://pykd.codeplex.com/):

```
>>> print module("rundll32")
Module: rundll32
Start: 7f0000 End: 7fe000 Size: e000
Image: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rundll32.exe
Symbols: e:\debug\symbols\rundll32.pdb\EFAE0C870C2846EDB63B9A7274CD50422\rundll32.pdb
Timestamp: 4a5bc637
Check Sum: 11cf2
```

With that information given, how can I find out more about the module, similar to the `lm vm <module>` command of WinDbg?

```
start    end        module name
007f0000 007fe000   rundll32   (deferred)             
    Image path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rundll32.exe
    Image name: rundll32.exe
    Timestamp:        Tue Jul 14 01:41:43 2009 (4A5BC637)
    CheckSum:         00011CF2
    ImageSize:        0000E000
    File version:     6.1.7600.16385
    Product version:  6.1.7600.16385
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        1.0 App
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     rundll
    OriginalFilename: RUNDLL32.EXE
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7600.16385
    FileVersion:      6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
    FileDescription:  Windows host process (Rundll32)
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Especially, I'd like to get the "OriginalFilename".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of that information is stored in the module's version resource information. You can access the version resource with the `queryVersion()` method. It takes a string parameter to specify the resource, e.g.

```
>>> m = module("rundll32")
>>> m.queryVersion("LegalCopyright")
'\xa9 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.'
```

Note how the parameter needn't be a version number, so the method name `queryVersion()` is a bit misleading.

Parameters:

- `CompanyName`
- `InternalName`
- `ProductName`
- `OriginalFilename`
- `ProductVersion`
- `FileVersion`
- `FileDescription`
- `LegalCopyright`

Other information present in `lm vm`:

- Start: `hex(m.begin())`
- End: `hex(m.end())`
- Name: `m.name()`
- File flags: `m.getFixedFileInfo().FileFlags`
- Checksum: `hex(m.checksum())`
- Timestamp: `hex(m.timestamp())`
- File OS: `hex(m.getFixedFileInfo().FileOS)`
- File Type: `hex(m.getFixedFileInfo().FileType)`
- File Date: `"%08X.%08X" % (m.getFixedFileInfo().FileDateLS , m.getFixedFileInfo().FileDateMS)`